# Como inserir um array dentro de um text area?

Tags: javascript, html5

Como inserir um array dentro de um text area?

```
var itens = new Array();

var index = 0;
function adicionaItem(item, quantidade) 
{
  itens[index] = {nomeItem : item, quantidade: quantidade};
  index++;
}

function concluirCompra() 
{
   document.getElementById("nota").innerHTML=itens[];//Aqui insere no textarea
}
```

Comment: Inserir como? Pode editar a pergunta com um exemplo do conteúdo que quer ver no textarea?

Comment: Não entendo o que você quer realmente. Você quer adicionar os nomes ou id's dos itens em um textatra?

Comment: Uma textarea é uma caixa de texto, se deseja inserir um vetor numa caixa de texto não faz muito sentido sem dizer como que o seu vetor deverá aparecer na forma de texto. Seria o mesmo que pedir para fazer o desenho do amor no papel.

Comment: Seria como se fosse um nota de compras, com Nome do produto e quantidade, seria uma matriz no caso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Texto Area</title>
    <script>
        var itens = new Array();
        var index = 0;  
        function adicionaItem(item, quantidade) 
        {
          itens[index] = {nomeItem : item, quantidade: quantidade};
          index++;
        }

        function concluirCompra() 
        {           
           document.getElementById("nota").innerHTML=getItensToString();
        }

        function getItensToString()
        {
            var result  = '';

            for (i = 0; i < itens.length; i++){
                result = result + itens[i]['nomeItem'] + ' ' + itens[i]['quantidade'] + '\r\n';
            }
            return result;
        }

        adicionaItem('cafe', 10);
        adicionaItem('arroz', 20);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="nota" name="nota"></textarea>
    <button type=button" onclick="concluirCompra();">Carregar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Explicação: Como a variável itens é um array de posições é só varrer cada posição para mostrar os dados no textarea, com uma quebra de linha `\r\n`.

***Referência***

- [JavaScript Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)